# automated document creation

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, documentation-generation

Are there any existing solutions to create documents in Silverlight? Looking to create purchase orders, contracts, etc.

Printing is a desired feature.

Comment: Do you mean a document that can be saved to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider sourcing from your customer, the *template* of those purchase orders, contracts, etc. Keep those documents on the server, and save their names/filepaths in the database.

Determine which fields need to be filled by the user, and create form elements (textbox, radio, image upload) for each of those document fields.

When the user has finished entering their data, save the data to a DB, and then programmatically insert their data into the document. You could manipulate a Word document/ text file, and then perhaps use a PDF generator to save in the user's 'inbox' on the server.

This likely is very business specific, so you'll have a lot of customization. Sounds like you were looking for an existing open source solution. Would be interesting to see if your solution ended up as a blogpost or open-source project at CodePlex or SourceForge. It really could be handy for others down the road!